# GRUB 2.06 unable to load kernel support module when booting after apt upgrade in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, apt, package-management, kernel, lsb-release

I run the most straightforward `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.

Now, when turning on and off the laptop strange console text appears on the screen. Furthermore, the GRUB menu is blue and blinking.

What has happened? How can I identify and fix it? The console text that appears is stuff about checks on OS processes.

EDIT 1:

I got some error during the Ubuntu boot process about SSSD (System Security Services Daemon) NSS and PAM services start:

[image: Error Screenshot]

EDIT 2:

The previous issue has been solved by commenting on the line `services = nss, pam` in the `sssd.conf` file.

Now I have another issue more critical:
*"Failed to start LSB: Symantec AutoProtect Modules."*

The error message is:

```
unable to load kernel support module (UNSUPPORTED-OS--UNK-UNK-5.15.0-71-generic-).
```

Of course the Linux image I am booting is version 5.15.0-71.

Maybe this error can arise from something I did during `apt upgrade`. Indeed I refused to install the new lsb-release version and keep the actual one.
Here is the apt log:

[image: apt log]

Comment: There is no way anyone can guess what text appears. As written there is noting here that can used to offer any help.

Comment: @David thank you for the feedback. It shows messages about checks on processes, wether they have started or ended.

Comment: That is the boot process that is then recorded into the log files. So you are past grub. Does last few lines show any errors? Often a video error. What video card/chip? And if nVidia, did you install correct nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository? Can you get grub menu and boot recovery mode? If UEFI, you press escape right after vendor logo & just before grub menu should appear to get grub menu. Sometimes a bit tricky on timing.

Comment: You need to provide a screenshot or log output before anyone can really help you.

Comment: @oldfred Thanks, for the hint! Probably by solving these errors, I will get the booting process to be as it was previously. Not sure, but it's worth trying.

Comment: @ArturMeinild thank you, that's the right way to proceed.

Comment: Is this a virus scanner? Symantec I do not know nor use a virus scanner. It may be settings or configuration of it that is the issue?